# Running anaconda python file, succussed in vs.code but fails in external command line

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am using anaconda in vs.code and developed a python script.

When tried to run the same python script from external command line, I got unexplained messages like:

"Pandas requires version '2.8.4' or newer of 'numexpr' (version '2.8.3' currently installed)." which weren't in the vs.code run. I am using the same python.exe the anaconda in vs.code uses.

Am I missing environment that existed in vs.code? How to run the python from external cmd which will work the same as inside the vs.code?

Comment: Kind of expected. VS Code Python extension takes care of loading virtual environments automatically for you, but your external command line might not. You need to learn the `conda` command further, such as how to use `conda activate` to load an environment. But that's for tutorials, not a specific question any more.

Comment: When you use external command line, please ensure that you've activated the corresponding Python interpreter.

Comment: I am familiar with the conda activate usage in command line. I understand the vs.code runs it automatically when I run the py file with anaconda installed. How can i find the exact command run by vs.code to launch and run the conda + py file?

Comment: Also when I use "Run python file" from the vs.code, I get the same error. Only when running "Run current file with interactive window" it runs without errors

Comment: By the way I am not running the py file from notebook, I am running directly the python file

Comment: I guess vs.code has its env. How do I run the same env from cmd?